# mb_convert_encoding work incorrecly with japanese character

Tags: character-encoding, php-8.1, php-8.2

On Php8, mb_detect_encoding working incorrect.
For example, i have code as bellow

```
$str = "苫小牧"; // assume that $str's encode is SJIS
// detect encoding of $str
$encode = mb_detect_encoding($str);
// convert 苫小牧 to EUC-JP 
$euc_str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, "EUC-JP",$encode);
```

In this case, mb_convert_encoding return garbled characters.
The reason is mb_detect_encoding detect encoding incorrect.
So, anybody can show solution for this case?
I think it need to create other function to detect encode instead of mb_detect_encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the manual page for `mb_detect_encoding`](https://www.php.net/mb_detect_encoding) says:

> Automatic detection of the intended character encoding can never be entirely reliable; without some additional information, it is similar to decoding an encrypted string without the key. It is always preferable to use an indication of character encoding stored or transmitted with the data, such as a "Content-Type" HTTP header.

Part of the way the function combats this is to require you to provide a *list of candidate encodings*. If none is provided directly to the function, they are taken from a global configuration state (see [mb_detect_order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php)).

For instance, taking the string you've provided, and using `$encode = mb_detect_encoding($sjis_str, 'EUC-JP,UTF-8,SJIS');` returns 'SJIS', and the conversion appears to proceed correctly, as demonstrated here: https://3v4l.org/KKf2h

The shorter the input, and the more candidates encodings you list, the more likely it is that `mb_detect_encoding` will guess wrong - the string may be equally valid in multiple encodings.

It's also worth noting that if the string is not valid in any of the encodings you list, `mb_detect_encoding` will return `false`, so if you are using it to process unknown strings, you should check `if ( $encode === false )` and add some appropriate error handling.